# Sklearn Random Feature Importances Identical for Predicting Different Response Variables

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I have created four random forest models they have the same X data, but their y data are four different response variables. The sklearn random forest feature importance is identical for all four. All four models achieve their purpose and make different predictions, but their random forest feature importance is the same.

Has anyone experienced this before?

I created the models with a series of nested objects like illustrated below. I used the same code before without having identical random forest feature importances, there was however the difference that inside each object I ran a 3-fold CV to determine max_features, whereas here I just used the default which is all of them.

Current code:

```
class NoCVMethod:
    def __init__(self, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, y, Method):
        self.clf = Method
        self.clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        self.predictions = self.clf.predict(X_test)
        self.rev_preds = rev_pred(y[-(13978+97):].values,self.predictions)
        self.residuals = y_test - self.rev_preds
        self.RMSE = np.mean((self.residuals)**2)**0.5
```

```
class Different_variables:
    def __init__(self, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, Method):
        self.TSS = NoCVMethod(X_train, y_train[y_train.columns.tolist()[0]], X_test, y_test[y_test.columns.tolist()[0]], y[y.columns.tolist()[0]], Method)
        self.NOx = NoCVMethod(X_train, y_train[y_train.columns.tolist()[1]], X_test, y_test[y_test.columns.tolist()[1]], y[y.columns.tolist()[1]], Method)
        self.NH4 = NoCVMethod(X_train, y_train[y_train.columns.tolist()[2]], X_test, y_test[y_test.columns.tolist()[2]], y[y.columns.tolist()[2]], Method)
        self.PO4 = NoCVMethod(X_train, y_train[y_train.columns.tolist()[3]], X_test, y_test[y_test.columns.tolist()[3]], y[y.columns.tolist()[3]], Method)
```

Old code:

```
class CVMethod:
    def __init__(self, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, y, param_dict, Method):
        self.pipeline = Pipeline([
            ('scale', StandardScaler()),
            ('clf', Method)
        ]) 
        self.param_grid = param_dict
        self.grid = GridSearchCV(self.pipeline, param_grid = self.param_grid, cv = 3, verbose = False, n_jobs = -1)
        self.grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
        self.predictions = self.grid.predict(X_test).ravel()
        self.rev_preds = rev_pred(y[-(13978+97):].values,self.predictions)
        self.residuals = y_test - self.rev_preds
        self.RMSE = np.mean((self.residuals)**2)**0.5
```

```
class CVDifferent_variables:
    def __init__(self, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, param_dict, Method):
        self.TSS = CVMethod(X_train, y_train[y_train.columns.tolist()[0]], X_test, y_test[y_test.columns.tolist()[0]], y[y.columns.tolist()[0]], param_dict, Method)
        self.NOx = CVMethod(X_train, y_train[y_train.columns.tolist()[1]], X_test, y_test[y_test.columns.tolist()[1]], y[y.columns.tolist()[1]], param_dict, Method)
        self.NH4 = CVMethod(X_train, y_train[y_train.columns.tolist()[2]], X_test, y_test[y_test.columns.tolist()[2]], y[y.columns.tolist()[2]], param_dict, Method)
        self.PO4 = CVMethod(X_train, y_train[y_train.columns.tolist()[3]], X_test, y_test[y_test.columns.tolist()[3]], y[y.columns.tolist()[3]], param_dict, Method)
``
```

Comment: could you give details on the four `y` ? What do you mean by different ?

Comment: @etiennedm the four different y are four different response variables (TSS, NOx, NH4, PO4). They differ in values and distribution.

Update: I think the problem comes with the self.clf property being overwritten, but I do not know why

Comment: in the `__init__` of your class `Method`, you are passing another `Method` as parameter, isn't it weird ? is that also a type `Method` ? (you should use lower case for argument if the class name exists)

Comment: Thanks, I understand better now. I think your previous comment might be the reason of the unexpected behaviour. I have just proposed a solution, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your `self.clf` *points* to your `Method`. At the end, you are probably printing the features importance of a unique classifier.

Maybe you should copy it:

```
from sklearn.base import clone

class NoCVMethod:
    [...]
    self.clf = clone(Method) # only copy the estimator
    # OR
    self.clf = deepcopy(Method) # if you want to also copy the data estimator
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701603/how-to-duplicate-an-estimator-in-order-to-use-it-on-multiple-data-sets) (or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576024/how-to-clone-an-scikit-learn-estimator-including-its-data) as you suggested) for more details about copying an sklearn estimator.

Comment: I had some errors with this method, something with an issue with cloning a method that does not take a set of parameters??

Anyway I tried a similar method from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576024/how-to-clone-an-scikit-learn-estimator-including-its-data and it worked. - Thank you so much :)

Comment: Hi @SebastianTopalian, I'm glad it helped. I have updated the answer to include your comment. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Haha thank you for teaching me the way of the community. I have been lurking for quite some time, but I figured it was time to get in on the action. :)